# How to properly give Wordpress its own directory

Tags: htaccess, directory, site-url

I'm sorry if this question is maybe a noob one, but I'm having some problems in correctly giving Wordpress its own directory and make it work.

I've installed WP in a subdirectory, like `www.example.com/my_subdir/`, and I want to access the site from `www.example.com`.

I've followed the instructions of the Codex [page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), namely on Method 1 (of course by correctly replacing my own URL's) but the site keeps on being accessed from `www.example.com/my_subdir/`.

This is the content of the `.htaccess` file inside the `root` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And this is the content of the `.htaccess` file inside the `my_subdir` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_subdir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my_subdir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I properly place Wordpress inside its own directory, and keep the site being accessed from the main `www.example.com` URL?

Comment: If you want it accessible from root, then you should follow the steps in Method II, not Method I

Comment: Just **COPY**  `index.php` and .`htaccess` into `www.example.com` _(so one folder higher then `my_subdir`  folder itself)_ Edit `index.php` and set it like `require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/my_subdir/wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: And add also in `wp-config.php` _(to prevent any change in the GUI admin area)_  `define( 'WP_HOME',        'http://example.com' );  define( 'WP_SITEURL',     'http://example.com/my_subdir' );`

Comment: It seems that wasn't working because of cache not being refreshed. I have used Method I, like described in the question, and it works (so, just by creating a new `.htaccess`, not copying `index.php`, and updating the URL's in the admin area, I can access the site from `www.example.com`). Is this not supposed to be the correct way?

Comment: I personally never add that into .htaccess _(I see no reason to do)_ , but thats just me. I even **move** the `wp-config.php` to the root of `example.com` and on two sites I have that config file outside the root. Do it as you wish to do, as long it works and bring no delay/errors to the site.